# Which is the best framework for Mapping in .NET?

Tags: .net, xamarin, mapping, automapper

Actually I am using Automapper, but I have read that, in terms of performance, is not the best option. Which one do you reccommend for me? **I am looking for a good performance.**

This is for a Xamarin project.

Comment: Try http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1009198/Expressmapper-The-New-NET-Mapper

Comment: I have tried to install it by Nuget but it is not compatible with Portable Class Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the absolute best performance, mapping manually "by hand" offers the best performance.

Anything past that is a tradeoff of features/convenience for performance.

We use the LINQ projection capabilities of AutoMapper, which pushes the projection down to the LINQ query provider level and subsequently the database. This actually performs better than a mapping by hand as it skips pulling back more data than needed into an intermediate domain model, and goes straight from SQL to DTO.